# Divide line in $XY$-dimension

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

For example we have line $A$ with coordinates $(0, 1, 10, 9)$;

And we need to divide this line by $3$ (so we have now $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$), where $A_1 + A_2 + A_3 = A$;
Is there equation, to find coordinates of $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ points?

With best regards

Comment: I think, for `A1` its `(10 - 0)/3, (9-1) / 3`;

Comment: What coordinates do you use for a line? It looks as if your coordinates describe a line segment in the plane by giving coordinates for its two end points. If so, in which order do you use them. Also, why do you want three *points* $A_i$ which add up to a *line*? If you want three four-element vectors that add up to a line, I'd interpret each such vector as a line in its own right.